# How can i change a stylesheet attribute outside it? React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const handlePress = e => {
    styles.button.borderColor = '#FF0000';
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handlePress}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Example</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    borderWidth: 10,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#8a2be2',
    width: 125,
    height: 125,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 25
  }
});
```

I try to change the value of the button borderColor calling a function to do this, but an error occurred saying: "Attempted to assign to readonly property"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change `state` for that, you can use `useState`, import it and then change the state on press:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false)
  const handlePress = e => {
    setButtonClicked(true)
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={buttonClicked?[styles.button, {borderColor: 'red'}]:styles.button} onPress={handlePress}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Example</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Still with the same error, nothing has changed: https://snack.expo.io/@gfguilherme/carefree-carrot

Comment: @Qiarash - state is not necessarily needed here. It depends on the use case, but he was not editing the style of the event object in the correct way, as I stated in my answer. State is an option, but this seems like too simple of a task to require state, especially if there are going to be multiple buttons. You are not going to want to maintain state for border color for each button on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to edit the styles object when you fire the onPress event. Instead of that, you need to edit the style of the event object passed by the event handler, which will be the element in this case. The styles object is used to apply styles when the component is loaded, but after that, you want to edit the instance of the element itself.

In your handlePress function, if you `console.log(e.target)`, you should see the element printed to the console after the press event is triggered. You will be able to see all the attributes associated with it and one of those attributes is style. That is the style attribute that you want to change. Like this:

```
  let obj = e.target;
  obj.style.borderColor = '#FF0000';
```

A good way to see what's happening with event handlers is to just console.log the object that you are getting from the event. You will understand if you are getting the correct or incorrect object and start to see all of the things you can do with it. Events are a big world with lots of options available. When in doubt, console.log!

Comment: I tried this [here](https://snack.expo.io/@gfguilherme/carefree-carrot) and as you can see, this worked to Web but when you try to run in a Android device, the follow error occur: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'obj.style.borderColor = '#FF0000")